# Google to index preferred sub-directory?

Tags: seo, google

I have inherited a rather large site built with Magento. When visiting the site it redirects by default to website.com/usa using a Magento PHP function (not .htaccess). When searching for the site, however, Google has indexed website.com/eu instead. Is there any way I can tell Google to index the /usa version instead of the /eu?

Geotargeting isn't really necessary right now as they are both showing the same content whilst the eu version is being built.

Comment: How is it indexing `/eu` _instead_? Surely it is indexing both versions otherwise someone has explicitly instructed Google to index `/eu` and not `/usa` on the website itself (and it is this that you will need to locate and change) - check robots meta tag and `robots.txt`.

Comment: Where are you searching from? Is it possible you are seeing _localised_ search results?

Answer (score 1):

google webmaster tools allows this.   simply add www.example.com/uk/ as first site , then in the geographic target tell google its for UK.   next add example.com/usa/ as second site and set geographic target if you dont want it to be a catch all.   now google will treat sub directory as a separate site with geo targeted results.

also for pages that exist between multiple sites (folders) make sure you have the correct hreflang meta tags setup.  they let google know there are multiple versions of the same page and thus prevent duplicate content penalties.   when you have hrerflang tags you can drop canonical domain to prevent confusion.  from our tests, hreflang is much higher weighted than canonical